# ExpandableListActivity how to check/uncheck checkbox in all children of a group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a ExpandableListActivity that has groups and children. the chidren have a checkbox. 
I've overridden setOnGroupExpandListener for when the user tap the group.

How can i check/uncheck the checkbox for each child for a particular group?

I've tried getting the adapter and calling getChild using the groupPosition but i'm lost in how do do this.

thanks in advance

```
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;



import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpList extends ExpandableListActivity
{





 String arrGroupelements[];
 String arrChildelements[][];
 private static final String TAG = ExpList.class.getSimpleName();
 DisplayMetrics metrics;
 int width;
 ExpandableListView expList;

 RROnCallApplication appObj;
 Cursor companies;
 Button mainMenu;

 ExpAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        appObj = (RROnCallApplication) getApplication();

        mainMenu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonmainmenu);
        mainMenu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(ExpList.this, MenuActivity2.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });



        try{

         companies = appObj.dbModel.queryAllFromCompanyBranch();
         arrGroupelements = new String[companies.getCount()  ];
         Log.e(TAG, "companies count  = " + companies.getCount());

         arrChildelements = new String[arrGroupelements.length][20];

         if(companies != null && companies.getCount() > 0){
             if(companies.moveToFirst()){

                 int i = 0;

                 do{

                     arrGroupelements[i] = companies.getString(companies.getColumnIndex(DBModel.C_COMPANYBRANCH_NAME));
                     Log.e(TAG, "arrGroupelements[" + i +"] = " + arrGroupelements[i]);

                     int compID = appObj.dbModel.getCompanyidFromName(arrGroupelements[i]);
                     Log.e(TAG, "compID = " + compID);

                     String[] branchesArr = appObj.dbModel.getBranchNamesfromCompanyId(compID);
                     Log.e(TAG, "branchesArr length = " + branchesArr.length);




                     for(int h = 0; h < branchesArr.length; h++){

                     arrChildelements[i][h] = branchesArr[h];

                     }

                    i++;
                 }while(companies.moveToNext());

                 Log.e(TAG, "arrGroupelements size = " + arrGroupelements.length);

             }//end of moveToFirst

         }


        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "There was a problem downloading companies and branches", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "********Exception = " + e.toString());
        }finally{

            companies.close();
        }







        expList = getExpandableListView();
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        //this code for adjusting the group indicator into right side of the view
        expList.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetDipsFromPixel(50), width - GetDipsFromPixel(10));
        expList.setAdapter(new ExpAdapter(this));


        expList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Log.e("onGroupExpand", "OK");



            }


        });

        expList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Log.e("onGroupCollapse", "OK");
            }
        });

        expList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Log.e("OnChildClickListener", "OK Group = " + groupPosition
                        + " child = " + childPosition);

                TextView tvBranchName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);
                String branchName = tvBranchName.getText().toString();

                Log.e(TAG, "branch name = " + branchName);

                int branchID = appObj.dbModel.getBranchIdFromName(branchName);

                Log.e(TAG, "branch ID = " + branchID);



                final CheckBox cb = ((CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox));

                if(cb.isChecked() == true){

                    Log.e(TAG, "checkBox is true but setting it to false now" );
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    appObj.dbModel.updateBranchSelectedStatus(String.valueOf(branchID), "N");
                    Log.e(TAG, "just called updateBranchSelectedStatus with values " + String.valueOf(branchID) + " " + "N");

                    Log.e(TAG, "Branhes selected are " + appObj.dbModel.getBranchList());


                }else{

                    Log.e(TAG, "checkBox is false but setting it to true");
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    appObj.dbModel.updateBranchSelectedStatus(String.valueOf(branchID), "Y");
                    Log.e(TAG, "just called updateBranchSelectedStatus with values " + String.valueOf(branchID) + " " + "Y");

                    Log.e(TAG, "Branhes selected are " + appObj.dbModel.getBranchList());



                }  



                return false;
            }
        });





    }//end of onCreate






    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        Intent i = new Intent(this, OnCallMenuActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }






    public int GetDipsFromPixel(float pixels)
    {
     // Get the screen's density scale
     final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
     // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
     return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
    }




    public class ExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context myContext;

        public ExpAdapter(Context context) {
            myContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
            }

            TextView tvPlayerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerName);
            tvPlayerName.setText(arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition]);

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            int branchID = appObj.dbModel.getBranchIdFromName(arrChildelements[groupPosition][childPosition]);
            Log.e(TAG, "inside getchildView and branchID = " + branchID);
            boolean isBranchSelected = appObj.dbModel.isBranchSelected(String.valueOf(branchID));
            Log.e(TAG, "isBranchSelected = " + isBranchSelected);

            if(isBranchSelected == true){

                cb.setChecked(true);
                Log.e(TAG, "inside getchildView and cb.setChecked(true)");

            }else{

                cb.setChecked(false);
                Log.e(TAG, "inside getchildView and cb.setChecked(false)");
            }




            return convertView;
        }

      @Override
      public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
       //return arrChildelements[groupPosition].length;

     int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < arrChildelements[groupPosition].length; i++)
        count += arrChildelements[groupPosition][i] != null ? 1 : 0;
      return count;
      }

      @Override
      public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
       return null;
      }

      @Override
      public int getGroupCount() {
       return arrGroupelements.length;
      }

      @Override
      public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
       return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
       }

       TextView tvGroupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroupName);
       tvGroupName.setText(arrGroupelements[groupPosition]);

         ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) parent;
         mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);


       return convertView;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean hasStableIds() {
       return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
       return true;
      }
     }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

try creating an array of arrays of booleans called checked. then in getChildView check if that spot in the array is true, if so so the checkbox to checked.
then when you expand a parent loop through every element in that two dimential array setting them all to true and then calling notifyDataSetChanged

```
boolean [][] checked;
```

then in on expand

```
for(int i =0; i < checked[groupPosition].size; i++)
{
    checked[groupPosition][i] = true;
}
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in getChildView you should also but this

```
cb.setChecked(checked[groupPosition][childPosition]);
```

a sim thing can be done to uncheck them by setting it to false. just remember to update this array when a user checks or unchecks a button so when the list views are recycled you dont get randomly checked boxes.